# How to access the value of a stack parameter?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, masm, irvine32

Extremely new to MASM here. I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the values passed into a procedure through the stack? For instance, here I try to simply add 2 vars, but the output gives me some crazy long address. Any suggestions?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
;//DECOY VARS
operand1   WORD    46
operand2   WORD    -20
dest       DWORD   0

.code
main PROC
push    operand1 ;[EBP + 16]
push    operand2 ;[EBP + 12]
push    OFFSET  dest ;[EBP + 8]
call    compute
call    writeint

exit
main ENDP

compute PROC
    push    ebp ;save ebp state
    mov     ebp, esp ;set ebp to activation record

    mov     eax, [ebp + 16]
    add     eax, [ebp + 12]

    pop     ebp
    ret     12
compute ENDP

END main
```

Comment: `push    operand1` is a 16-bit push because `operand1` is only a `WORD`!  You need to zero-extend into a register so you can do a 32-bit push that fills a whole stack slot.

Comment: @PeterCordes , This totally worked and clarified everything, thank you!

Comment: Cheers.  I looked for a duplicate about how to actually do the zero-extending (e.g. `movzx eax, word ptr [operand1]`) but didn't find a duplicate for that part.  Maybe I should reopen and answer this, since passing narrow args to a function in MASM is something people could google on.  But I probably won't bother unless you want to post a self-answer; let me know and I can reopen if you (or other future readers) want to do that.